# Wrap text consistently in table cells

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an HTML table with a column of cells containing two parts e.g.

```
| Cat (meow)                |
+---------------------------+
| Long-dinosaur-name (roar) |
```

There are also other columns not shown. My users' browsers have unknown widths. On a wide one, I wish to show the cell as one line, as above. If it gets too narrow, I'm fine with wrapping

```
| Cat      |
| (meow)   |
+----------+
| Long-    |
| dinosaur-|
| name     |
| (roar)   |
```

but if one line wraps, all lines must also wrap:

```
| Cat                 |
| (meow)              |
+---------------------+
| Long-dinosaur-name  |
| (roar)              |
```

Without using Javascript, is it possible to do this?

I know I can use `<td nowrap>` to prevent wrapping, or `<br>` to force a wrap, but how can I make one cell depend on another?

Comment: Would giving the td a fixed width not solve your problem?

Comment: @Miaan, that would make either the table wrap when there is no need to (when the browser is wide enough), or the user have to scroll right (browser too narrow).

Answer (score 1):

Try using media query(CSS) with breakpoints. I know you said, the user browsers width's are unknown, but you can anticipate for different width's etc